# How do you get the number of words in a NSTextStorage/NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So my question is basically how do you get the number of words in a NSTextStorage/NSString?  I don't want the character length but the word length.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on 10.6 or later, the following may be the easiest solution:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfWordsInString:(NSString *)str {
    __block NSUInteger count = 0;
    [str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])
                            options:NSStringEnumerationByWords|NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        count++;
    }];
    return count;
}
```

If you want to take the current locale into account when doing word-splitting you can also add NSStringEnumerationLocalized to the options.

Answer (score 1):

You could always find the number of spaces and add one.
To be more accurate one would have to take into all nonletter characters: commas, fullstops, whitespace characters, etc.

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count];
```

Comment: Yes, I though about that.  But what if I use 2 spaces instead of just 1 after a full stop (Which is what I do now.)?

Comment: You could search through the string, and replace all double spaces with a single space.
[[[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] count];

Answer (score 1):

When using `NSTextStorage`, you can use the `words` method to get to the number of words. It might not be the most memory-efficient way to count words, but it does a pretty good job at ignoring punctuation marks and other non-word characters:

```
NSString *input = @"one - two  three   four .";
NSTextStorage *storage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:input];
NSLog(@"word count: %u", [[storage words] count]);
```

The output will be `word count: 4`.

Answer (score 0):

`CFStringTokenizer` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
NSArray *words = [theStorage words];
int wordCount = [words count];
```

Is that your problem?